# $n^4+2n^3+2n^2+2n+1=m^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find all integer solutions $(n,m)$ to $$n^4+2n^3+2n^2+2n+1=m^2$$

My attempt,

$$n^4+2n^3+2n^2+2n+1=(n^2+n+1)^2-n^2$$

$$=(n^2+n+1-n)(n^2+n+1+n)$$

$$=(n^2+1)(n^2+2n+1)$$

$$=(n^2+1)(n+1)^2$$

So I ended up, $(n^2+1)(n+1)^2=m^2$

I'm stuck here. Can anyone continue for me or is there another way to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the other two terms are perfect squares, you now have to ask yourself, when is $n^2+1$ a perfect square?

Answer (score 3):

If $n=-1$ then $m=0$. On the other hand, if $n\not=-1$ then
$$\sqrt{n^2+1}=\frac{|m|}{|n+1|}\in\mathbb{Q}.$$
So $n^2+1$ should be a perfect square which implies that $n=0$ and $m=\pm 1$.

Answer (score 0):

For $(n,m) = (0,1), (0,-1), (-1,0)$ are the solutions. Other than that, $\left(\dfrac{n^2}{n+1}\right)^2 = n^2+1\implies \left(n-1 + \dfrac{1}{n+1}\right)^2 = n^2+1$. The left side is not an integer while the right side is. This is enough to say the equation has no integer solutions.

Comment: How about n=0,m=1?

Comment: Indeed don't forget about the special case where n=0

Comment: You may wish to reword your conclusion "This is enough to say the equation has no integer solutions." to reflect the fact that you are still excluding n=0 from that statement